# numpy where search multiple conditions with a precomputed series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list with a multiple series with booleans and pandas DataFrame. The number of series in the list varies.

```
s1 = {Series: (4,)} (0, True) (1, True) (2, True) (3, True)
s2 = {Series: (4,)} (0, True) (1, True) (2, True) (3, False)
list_with_series = [s1, s2]

df = {DataFrame: (4, 8)}
```

I want to use numpy.where to add a column to DataFrame with a tag like this:

```
df['Tag'] = numpy.where(' & '.join(list_with_series), 'Tag_name', '')
```

When I try to join series, I get this error:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, Series found
```

I cant directly specify series like `numpy.where(s1 & s2)`, because number of series are dynamic.
I also try to use numpy because it is less memory intensive.

What is the best way to match and tag rows in DataFrame, not changing of using precomputed series with booleans? Is it even possible to use numpy in such scenario?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it even python, the code you posted? I can't understand what's this `s1 = {Series: (4,)} (0, True) (1, True) (2, True) (3, True)`. Can you post the working code?

Comment: It's how it is looking in pycharm debugger. It's a representation of the series, I guess it is a return of magic __str__ method.
For us it is a series with 4 boolean elements

Comment: Ohh okay. Thanks for the clarification. Understood :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `' & '.join(...)` in this case, the expectancy is that you'll pass strings, not series. This is the error.

In this case, you could use:

```
import numpy as np

np.logical_and.reduce([s.values for s in list_with_series])
```

Comment: Are there any way to use logical and among multiple series to get only one, where:

True and True = True;

True and False = False

?

It should help me to cut down multiple series to only one and use it in np.where function.

Comment: Oh, i get it. That's exactly what you advised me